# java call unsynched from synched

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

```
public synchornized void mySyncedMethod(int myVar){
  unsynchedMethod(int myvar);
}

private void unsynchedMethod(int myVar){
  ...
  do lots of processing
  ...
  incrementStateVar += myVar;
}
```

thread A starts, then thread B starts.  If thread B processing takes less time than A, could B complete (and increment state var) before A.

Comment: You only have a problem if you have code that makes direct call to `unsynchedMethod(nnn)` without going through the synchronized method `mySyncedMethod(nnn)`.

Answer (score 0):

If two threads call a synchronized method of the same object, only one can enter, the other waits until the first one exits and unlocks the object. So if threads A and B call the synchronized method of the same object, only one can increment the var.